# Custom MKMapView annotation display is not showing User Location

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, annotations, mkmapview

I have an application with a flipside view and a main view. The main view copies information contained in an array from the application delegate, and pushes the useful information into a for loop which then takes the name, GPS coords, and other identifying information and passes that into a series of methods and classes which result in a custom annotation. However, every time I try and change the settings of my app in the flipside view, and then return to the main view the users location dissapears. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a beginner but as only as a suggestion, have you tried saving the user location to the user default and then recalling it when you go the the main view?

I have found that data you think persists does not persist between screens.